# how to use slug in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i don't know how to make url like this

> tkd/index.php/article/77/Kejurnas-2013

i am getting error  with url like this

> tkd/index.php/article/77/Kejurnas%202013

this is my controller

```
public function index($id = null, $slug = FALSE){

    // Fetch the article
    $this->db->where('pubdate <=', date('Y-m-d'));
    $this->data['article'] = $this->mberita->get_by_id($id,$slug);
    //echo '<pre>' . $this->db->last_query() . '</pre>';
   // dump($this->data['article']);


    // Return 404 if not found
    count($this->data['article']) || show_404(uri_string());

    // Redirect if slug was incorrect
    $requested_slug = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $set_slug = $this->data['article']->slug;
    if ($requested_slug != $set_slug) {
        redirect('article/' . $this->data['article']->id . '/' . $this->data['article']->slug, 'location', '301');
    }

    // Load view
    /*add_meta_title($this->data['article']->judul_berita);*/
    $this->data['contents'] = 'article';
    $this->load->view('template/wrapper/mahasiswa/wrapper_article', $this->data);

}
```

and this is my modal

```
public function get_by_id($id = 0, $slug = FALSE)
    { 
      if ($id === 0 && $slug === FALSE)
      {
        $query = $this->db->get('$this->tbl_berita');
        return $query->result_array();
      }

      return $this->db->get_where($this->tbl_berita, array('id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug),1)->row();

    }
```

please help me how to make the right url. thank you

Comment: Why even consider slug? I mean consider only ID and if ID is valid dont bother with anything behind `/{id}/whatever-is-here`. I mean,sure put pseudo slug in place for "nice" url reason but dont consider it (at least in my apps I don't, its only for "show").

Comment: you also dont have to url_encode hyphens

Comment: i always delete urkk_encode but its same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of CodeIgniters helper functions `url_title()`

> Takes a string as input and creates a human-friendly URL string. This
>   is useful if, for example, you have a blog in which you'd like to use
>   the title of your entries in the URL.

```
site_url("articles/{ID}/").url_title({TITLE});
```

Comment: i alraedy takes helper function like that but when i dump($this->data['article']); output is Dump => array(0) {}. you can see my explanation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020750/how-to-get-article-by-id-in-codeigniter