# how to get article by id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

example i have 3 article each article have button "read more". and i am getting 1 article have  array like this.

```
    Dump => object(stdClass)#21 (6) {
  ["id"] => string(2) "76"
  ["id_admin"] => string(0) ""
  ["judul_berita"] => string(5) "kasus"
  ["content"] => string(449) "                                
                              This is my first use of nestedsortable.js in a custom cms creation with codeigniter, So I use it with Codeigniter php framework. I have an ordered and nested list(for order pages) and I need to convert this list to array with 'toArray' but it's not working the error message: uncaught typeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined this is my js code:
                            "
  ["tanggal"] => string(10) "2014-03-25"
  ["slug"] => string(5) "kasus"
}
```

and 2 other article like this

```
    Dump => array(0) {
}
```

where is error code?

my controller

```
    public function index($id = null, $slug = FALSE){
 // Fetch the article
        $this->db->where('pubdate <=', date('Y-m-d'));
        $this->data['article'] = $this->mberita->get_by_id($id,$slug);
        dump($this->data['article']);
       }
```

my model

```
function get_by_id($id, $slug)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($this->tbl_berita, array('id' => $id,  'slug' => $slug),1)->row();
    }
```

please help me what to do. thank you.

please check this code any wrong in there?

```
// Redirect if slug was incorrect
    $requested_slug = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $set_slug = $this->data['article']->slug;
    if ($requested_slug != $set_slug) {
        redirect('article/' . $this->data['article']->id . '/' . url_title($this->data['article']->slug), 'location', '301');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because row() retrieves a single row. better use `fetch_object` or any other method.

You can know more about this in codeigniter documentation- [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)